# 100 students in two classrooms.

Tags: combinatorics

> Given 100 *distinct* students and two classrooms: A and B, of 60 and 45 seats respectively. In how many ways can a professor split the students into the two classrooms with respect to their capacities?

I've went as far as considering how to "distribuite" the 5 empty seats into the two class rooms:

6!/5! = 6

which are the cases in which the occupied seats are:

- 60 - 40
- 59 - 41
- 58 - 42
- 57 - 43
- 56 - 44
- 55 - 45

Now, considering for example the first case, since the order in which they are chosen doesn't matter, we just have to pick 60 students from the group of 100 and place them in A; then for the second case, similarly, pick 59 from the 100; and so on, leading us to:

$$\binom{100}{60} + \binom{100}{59} + \binom{100}{58} + \binom{100}{57} + \binom{100}{56} + \binom{100}{55}$$

for a total of:

$$6 * (\binom{100}{60} + \binom{100}{59} + \binom{100}{58} + \binom{100}{57} + \binom{100}{56} + \binom{100}{55})$$

I feel like I'm missing something, though. Is this correct? If not, how so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum $\binom{100}{60}+\cdots +\binom{100}{55}$ is a correct expression for the answer. A clear explanation has been given for why it is right. There is no reason to multiply by $6$.

Comment: Oh right, silly mistake.